# Variable does not exist in type

Tags: angular

Trying to populate an array of a Product data type for test purposes in the `ngOnInit` function as seen below:

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {IProduct} from "../product-list/product";
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-product-detiail',
      templateUrl: './product-detiail.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./product-detiail.component.css']
    })
    export class ProductDetiailComponent implements OnInit {
      pageTitle = "Product Detail";
      product: IProduct[];

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.pageTitle = `:${id}`;

        this.product = {
          "productId": 10,
          "productName": "Saw",
          "productCode": "TBX-0022",
          "releaseDate": "May 15, 2016",
          "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw",
          "price": 11.55,
          "starRating": 3.7,
          "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png"
      };
      }
    }
```

I have the `IProduct` data type specified in an interface which can be seen here:

```js
export interface IProduct{
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    productCode: string;
    releaseDate: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    starRating: number;
    imageUrl: string; 
}
```

As can be seen the interface and the data given in the `ngOnInit` match but when the code compiles I am met with this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/product-detail/product-detiail.component.ts(24,7): error TS2322: Type '{ "productId": number; "productName": string; "productCode": string; "releaseDate": string; "description": string; "price": number; "starRating": number; "imageUrl": string; }' is not assignable to type 'IProduct[]'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"productId"' does not exist in type 'IProduct[]'.
```

I am very confused as to why this would happen? What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `product: IProduct[]` to `product: IProduct`

You have defined `product` as array of IProduct -> `IProduct[]` and assigned a single object of Type `IProduct` to it. Therefore you got this error.

To assign product in type `IProduct[]`, do this:

```
 product: IProduct[] = [
 {
      "productId": 10,
      "productName": "Saw",
      "productCode": "TBX-0022",
      "releaseDate": "May 15, 2016",
      "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw",
      "price": 11.55,
      "starRating": 3.7,
      "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png"
  }
]
```

or,

`product : IProduct[]= []`

```
product.push(
 {
      "productId": 10,
      "productName": "Saw",
      "productCode": "TBX-0022",
      "releaseDate": "May 15, 2016",
      "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw",
      "price": 11.55,
      "starRating": 3.7,
      "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png"
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, so you can't have an array with just one single object?

Comment: You have to modify lil bit for this. I am adding the solution

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if this makes sense

Comment: You have to wrap your object with `[]`

Comment: @JohnAlex Have you checked?